# Which git hooks to install for automatic version numbering

Tags: git, versioning, githooks

I have a script writing/updating a file with versioning info for my software. It is based on git describe and basically just counts commits since the last tag. Is there any best-practice in which git hooks to run this script in so that all developers always have up-to-date versioning info before compilation independent of the specific workflow they updated their working copy with? I'm especially thinking about the very typical ones:

- committing/pushing
- pulling
- merging
- initially cloning

and I'm sure I'm missing some. Is there a single hook which can cover all of these cases or do I have to install multiple ones? Is there any natural best choice? Does it make sense to put the generated versioning file under version control or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to not use hooks for this, as each developer has to setup these hooks manually after cloning, or at least by triggering some setup script that installs them. You cannot control the hooks in the developers repositories centrally.

Instead I'd recommend to make your build procedure update this file from the Git information, as you surely have some build tool in use.